# Eigenvalues are still eigenvalues on restricted subspace?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, direct-sum

Let's assume we have some Hilbert space $H$ and for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ let $H_k\subset H$ be a subspace such that
$$\bigoplus_{k\in \mathbb{N}} H_k =H$$
and all $H_k$ are mutually orthogonal.
Let $T:\operatorname{dom}(T)\subset H\to H$ be some linear, bounded, closed and densely defined operator. We assume that $T$ leaves $H_k$ invariant for any $k$ and $H_k\subset dom(T)$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Assume there exists $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ some eigenvalue of $T$, i.e. $\lambda-T$ is not injective. Can we find some $k_0\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\lambda$ can be associated with some $x\in H_{k_0}$,i.e. $Tx=\lambda x$?
Due to the property of the direct sum, for any $x,x'\in H$ we have
$$x=\sum_{k\in K}x_k,\quad x'=\sum_{k'\in K'}x_{k'}$$
for some finite sets $K,K'$. Let $x,x'\in H$, $x\neq x'$ so that
$$(\lambda-T)x=(\lambda-T)x'\Leftrightarrow \sum_{k\in K} (\lambda-T)x_k=\sum_{k'\in K'} (\lambda-T)x_{k'}.$$
How can I proceed?

Comment: In general I think the answer is no. You are asking that for *every* countable decomposition of $H$ into direct summands, there is a subspace $H_k$ which is the eigenspace of $\lambda$.

Comment: You can maybe have that there will be a $H_k$ *containing* the eigenspace of $\lambda$, if it has geometric multiplicity $1$, but the question's a bit vague with "associated"

Comment: Usually when people speak of a direct sum of Hilbert spaces they mean the completed direct sum of orthogonal subspaces, not the algebraic direct sum which you seem to be assuming.

Comment: Is there any hope if I assume the subspaces to be mutually orthogonal?

Comment: Do you also assume that each subspace $H_k$ is contained in the domain of $T$? If this is the case the conclusion holds.

Comment: How can one show this?